# Bash: Limiting CPU usage of all processes with a specified name

Tags: bash, centos, cpu-usage

I'm running JVM instances on a CentOS 6.3 x64 machine. Sometimes the CPU usage of one goes rampant and I/O blocks the entire machine.

How can I limit the usage of all Java processes to a single core? Or two cores? Or as specified?

I've tried `cpulimit`, which has failed to work for multiple cores, as well as multiple processes with the same name.

Is there a simple way to limit the CPU usage of all processes of a specified name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think all you need is [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) (to find the PIDs) and [`taskset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset). And then depending on your needs you'd run (as superuser) something like:

```
for pid in $(pgrep <pattern>);
do
  taskset -p 0x00000001 $pid
done
```

Consult the `taskset` manual page for more information on how to use it. You may need to install the `schedutils` package.

Of course you can vary that scheme to whatever complexity you desire, by modifying the processor mask (i.e. which CPU you assign).

I should add that I *think* `cpuset` (assuming you meant that, I'm not aware of a tool named `cpulimit` but that doesn't mean anything) uses the same underlying mechanisms. Therefore this may be in vain just as your past attempts.

Comment: I used `taskset` on an individual process but it continues to use up to 3 threads. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: @hexacyanide: nope, I don't because I don't know the exact program (and even if I did it might not make a difference). But threads are an "entity" inside a process. Indeed every process has a single thread at least (technically). The thread is what executes a "thread of instructions", figuratively speaking, whereas the process is the container providing memory space and so on. However, with `taskset` all of these threads would still be confined to using the CPU or CPUs you assigned in the processor mask ...